# Unity syntax errors LaserSound does not play when I press spacebar?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I trying to get the enemy ship to shoot the player ship tagged player
I receive one error: Assets/Scripts/EnemyAttack.cs(11,13): error CS0246:  The type or namespace name `EnemyAtack' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? I tried creating a class for the enemy attack but did not work. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;


 public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
 {
[SerializeField] GameObject[] enemyGuns;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    AddSphereCollider();
}

private void AddSphereCollider()
{
Collider sphereCollider = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
    sphereCollider.isTrigger = false;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "player")
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I thought I asked correctly I guess not :(

Comment: Both answers together are correct. 1. your component is already called `LaserSound` so you can't have a field with the same name. 2. You can only `Play` an `AudioSource` not an `AudioClip`

Comment: I made some changes and reposted the changes if you don't mind looking over it for me I receive no syntax error and its hard to figure out what missing. any guidance is appreciated I believe I followed everyone's advice in my first post. Thank you

Comment: It is working now Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Stop() and PlayOneShot() are both functions associated with the AudioSource class.

AudioSources are used to play AudioClips, in this case you need to add an AudioSource reference to your monobehaviour and add an AudioSource to your prefab, then link the reference and call your PlayOneShot() and Stop() functions on the AudioSource instead.

The other issue is your AudioClip is named LaserSound and your Monobehaviour is also called LaserSound.
Rename one or the other.

Comment: Thank you for your reply will work on this. and I will respond back when solved :)

Comment: I tried my best but didn't work out for me. Thank you though :(

Comment: You should probably go through the Unity tutorials on sound: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/audio/audio-listeners-sources

Answer (score 0):

Change

`[SerializeField] private AudioClip LaserSound;`

to

```
[SerializeField] private AudioClip laserSound;
```

and that should work. "AudioClip LaserSound" is basically the equivalent of "Classname AnotherClassname"

Comment: explained a bit complicated but in simple words: your component is already called `LaserSound` so you can't have a field with the same name within it.

Comment: Okay will try this Thank you for your feedback :)